# Proper way to send mail with different body using Python

Tags: python, function, sendmail

I'm wondering which approach is better for sending mail with different body using Python:

- send each mail using separate functions
- using one function and select body message with if-else statement

First case:

```
FROM = *from_email_address*

def send_mail_notify():

    SUBJECT = *some_subject_for_notification_event*
    TEXT = *any_text*

    msg = EmailMessage()
    msg['From'] = FROM
    msg['To'] = *to_email_address*
    msg['Subject'] = SUBJECT
    msg.set_content(TEXT)
    
    ...(initialize connection to mail server, etc.)
```

```
FROM = *from_email_address*

def send_mail_error():

    SUBJECT = *some_subject_for_error_event*
    TEXT = *any_text*

    msg = EmailMessage()
    msg['From'] = FROM
    msg['To'] = *email_address*
    msg['Subject'] = SUBJECT
    msg.set_content(TEXT)
    
    ...(initialize connection to mail server, etc.)
```

Second case:

```
FROM = *from_email_address*

def send_mail(param):

    if param == "notify":
        SUBJECT = *some_subject_for_notification_event*
        TEXT = *any_text*
    elif param == "error":
        SUBJECT = *some_subject_for_error_event*
        TEXT = *any_text*

    msg = EmailMessage()
    msg['From'] = FROM
    msg['To'] = *email_address*
    msg['Subject'] = SUBJECT
    msg.set_content(TEXT)

   ...(initialize connection to mail server, etc.)
```

Comment: Better for what? Readability or performance?

Comment: Readability is similar in both cases. How about performance?

Comment: Your question seems quite confused. You would use a single function, but pass as parameters any details which differ between messages. See also the [DRY principle.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create an unlimited functions for different types of `subject` and `text` and you don't need to check the condition with if-else statement:

```
FROM = *from_email_address*

def notify():
    return {"SUBJECT":"notification", "TEXT": "new message"}

def error():
    return {"SUBJECT":"error: message dont send", "TEXT": "error message text"}

def send_mail(param):
    msg = EmailMessage()
    msg['From'] = FROM
    msg['To'] = *email_address *
    msg['Subject'] = globals().get(param)()["SUBJECT"]
    msg.set_content(globals().get(param)()["TEXT"])
```

The `param` value must be the same as the name of the `function`.

Comment: Your solution is based on passing function (which contains necessary data) as argument for send_mail function, am I right?

Comment: Hi. in my code, you can run ``send_mail("notify")`` or ``send_mail("error")``. if your param is ``notify`` then notify function called and if your param is ``error`` the error function is called to change your subject and text mail.

Comment: @Boba_Fett thank you. So do you accepted this answer to others?